# In $\Delta ABC$, find the value of $\frac{a\cos A+b\cos B +c\cos C}{a+b+c}$ in terms of $r$ and $R$

Tags: triangles

$$\frac{R(\sin 2A+\sin 2B+\sin 2C)}{a+b+c}$$
$$=\frac{R(4\sin A \sin B\sin C)}{2R(\sin A+\sin B+\sin C}$$
$$=\frac{8R\sin \frac A2 \sin \frac B2 \sin \frac C2 \cos \frac A2 \cos \frac B2 \cos \frac C2}{8R\cos \frac A2 \cos \frac B2 \cos \frac C2}$$
$$=\frac{2r}{8R}$$
$$=\frac {r}{4R}$$
But the answer given is $\frac{r}{R}$

**R means the circumradius of the triangle**

**r is the inradius**

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit my bad, fixed it.

Comment: Can you test the right factor for the expression in the title (that *should* also be in the text of the question, with a mention that we want to compute it in terms of $r,R$, if we do indeed have to do this) in the special case $a=b=c$? (An edit to make things clear is welcome.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second line, you have a factor of $4$ in the numerator, so the numerator in the third line should be $4 \times (2 \times 2 \times 2) = 32$. The rest is fine.